# how to zoom a pane in config using tmuxinator

Tags: tmux

So what i want is to start a tmux session using tmuxinator and the vim pane would be zoomed in (prefex + z) but how can I specify that in tmuxinator ?

```
name: app
root: ~/work/app

windows:
  - rails:
    - cd server&&vim
    - guard
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [solution](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator/issues/259#issuecomment-59915285) worked for me

```
windows:
  - some_window:
    - editor:
      panes:
         - editor:
           - vim
           - C-b z
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside tmux at some pane shell if you write

```
tmux resize-pane -Z
```

That's equivalent to 'Prefix z' , keep that in your mind you can configure tmux through the shell

so Your tmuxinator project become

```
name: app
root: ~/work/app

windows:
  - rails:
    - tmux resize-pane -Z&&cd server&&vim
    - guard
```

That's will work , but you can do better by following [tmuxinator approach](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator#passing-directly-to-send-keys) instead of using '&&':

```
name: app
root: ~/work/app

windows:
  - rails:
    - server :
        - tmux resize-pane -Z
        - cd server
        - vim
    - guard
```